# Get the offset of any element such as anchor or img in jquery masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

im making a list of images in the page with jquery masonry and result correclty loaded according masonry effect but`when i user the`

```
   function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
        var aTag = $("a[id='" + aid + "']");
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: aTag.offset().top }, 'slow');
    }
```

im changing  "atag.offset" with position but cant get correct position or offset of element

Answer (score 1):

If you could use Masonry as an Isotope mode, you have access to the itemPositionDataEnabled method [described here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html) to expose each elements position in order to scroll to it. Regular scroll to methods won't work, because each element is absolutely positioned within the relatively positioned container div.